# How to open a file from the integrated terminal in VSCode to a new tab

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

If my script is run within vscode, it want it to open a .txt file in a new tab in vscode.  Else, open the folder containing the file.  However, the current "code" command opens it in the terminal  window instead of a new edit tab.

```
if ($env:TERM_PROGRAM -eq 'vscode') {
  code 'C:\temp\_Release_Evidence\test.txt'
}
else {
  explorer 'C:\temp\_Release_Evidence'
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce. On my system it opens the text file in a new tab in vscode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Normally, `code` refers Visual Studio Code's CLI, which is assumed to be in one of the directories listed in `$env:PATH`**:

- On Windows, it refers to the `code.cmd` batch file that serves as the CLI entry point.
- On Unix-like platforms it refers to a `code` Bash script.

**Its default behavior *is* to open a given file as a *new tab* in the most recently activated Visual Studio Code window** (which, when run from *inside* Visual Studio Code, is by definition the *current* window).

If that doesn't happen for you, perhaps `code` refers to a different executable on your machine:

- To avoid ambiguity, use the full CLI path instead, which, however, requires you to know Visual Studio Code's install location; typical CLI locations are:

  - Windows: `$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd`
  - macOS: `/usr/local/bin/code`
  - Linux: `/usr/bin/code`
- On Windows, something as simple as including the filename extension in the invocation - i.e., `code.cmd` - may help.

---

However, **assuming you're using the PIC (PowerShell Integrated Console)**, a specialized PowerShell shell that **comes with the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell)** for Visual Studio Code, a **workaround that also performs better**, because it doesn't require launching a child process:

- The PIC comes with the **`psedit` command** (an alias for the `Open-EditorFile` function), which quickly opens one or more files in a tab in the current Visual Studio Code  window.

  - Caveat: As of version v2022.5.1 of the PIC, specifying *multiple* files only works meaningfully if they are *individually enumerated*, as literal paths. If you try to use a *wildcard* pattern or a *directory* path, all matching files / files in the directory are uselessly opened *in sequence* in a *single* tab.

Thus, you could use the following:

```bash
if ($env:TERM_PROGRAM -eq 'vscode') {
  # Use `psedit`, if available; `code` otherwise.
  $exe = if ((Get-Command -ErrorAction Ignore psedit)) { 'psedit' } else { 'code' }
  & $exe 'C:\temp\_Release_Evidence\test.txt'
}
else {
  explorer 'C:\temp\_Release_Evidence'
}
```

Comment: It seems 'code' on my system refers to something else.  Which I don't know how to fix. But using 'Open-EditorFile' works great.  And it should only happen if I am in vscode.  Thanks @mklement0

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this or explain why this might occur on your system. Running the following whether in the **PowerShell Integrated Terminal** (which [@mklement0 explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72494163) succinctly) or a standard PowerShell terminal in VS Code's Terminal pane should open the file in a new tab where file contents are normally displayed:

```
code /path/to/file.txt
```

A suitable workaround may be to get the contents of a text file and pipe them in via `STDIN`. We can do this by adding a hyphen `-` as an empty parameter to `code` when piping data to it:

```
# Tip: Use the gc alias for Get-Content
Get-Content /path/to/file.txt | code -
```

You can then use `Save As...` to save the file to its intended target once you make your changes. You will need to use `Ctrl+C` in the terminal to close the input stream if you need to run additional commands before closing the file or saving to a one.

---

Even if this isn't a suitable workaround for you, it's a handy tip in other scenarios. For example, the following command will open documentation for `Get-Process` inside VSCode:

> **Reminder:** Don't forget to hit `Ctrl+C` in the terminal once the content finishes populating to be able to run additional commands, or close the temporary file buffer.

```
Get-Help Get-Process -Detailed | code -
```